# Careers RSS feed does not limit results on location

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs, feed

I am trying to get job details through a Careers RSS feed, but it does not return the proper data.

When I try the below URL I expect C# jobs from London:

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed?tags=c#&location=london

However, it also returns jobs from USA, Germany, Sydney.

Comment: Any reference if this is *expected* to work? (Like: where did you find that `location` parameter?) Also note that in a browser you'd need to encode the hash (#). Note sure about RSS clients though. You can easily test by changing the order of `tags` and `location`.

Answer (score 6):

Fix your URL.

Anything after a `#` will not be sent to a server - it is treated as a fragment.

You need to URL encode it to %23:

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed?tags=c%23&location=london